# сгенерировать 100 случайных чисел от -1000 до 1000 с помощью IntStream

Tags: java

Как мне завернуть данный stream в коллекцию типа TreeSet
Я пробовал запись

```
TreeSet<Integer> collect = IntStream.range(-1000, 1000).limit(100).collect(TreeSet::new);
```

Но не получилось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TreeSet<Integer> set = IntStream.range(-1000, 1000)
                                .limit(100)
                                .boxed()
                                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
```